# Keyboard doesn't appear on Iphone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, textfield

I have added to some rows from table view an TextField like this :

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
        //cell.alpha = 0.65;

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            code=[[UITextField alloc] init];
            code.frame = CGRectMake(200,10,80,50);
            code.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            code.text=@"515800";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:code];

        }
        if(indexPath.row==2)
        {
            ville=[[UITextField alloc] init];
            ville.frame = CGRectMake(200,10,80,50);
            ville.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            ville.text=@"Paris";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:ville];

        }
        if(indexPath.row==4)
        {
            nomdepartenaire=[[UITextField alloc] init];
            nomdepartenaire.frame = CGRectMake(200,10,80,50);
            nomdepartenaire.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            nomdepartenaire.text=@"Alliantis Ttttt";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:nomdepartenaire];

        }
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that the keyboard doesn't appear if I want to change the text from TextField. Why?

Comment: make sure you arent adding anything on top of the textfield

Comment: try to add the text view inside the cell's content view:
cell.contentView addSubview:labl
Also check the text view is inside the cell view frame (I noticed your textview has an y origin of 10 and the height of 50, so your table cell must have a height of 60 at least).

Comment: also check that cell's userinterection should be enabled

Comment: the position of textfield is ok,because I see it on screen where it must be. But the keyboard doesn't show up yet..:(

Comment: where is cell's userinterection ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is something in the way of the text field and that makes it not receiving the touch event. Adding the entire cellForRowAtIndexPath would probably help us understand better what's happenning. Also, you should add the texfield and other custom elements to `cell.contentsView`, not directly to the cell.

Comment: I added the entire ceelForRowAtIndexPath